# Reading integer values from a file in c

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to read data from a file to store his first n elements in an array. The data is an integer sequence:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...
```

When I check the content of the array, I don't find the correct values, it seems like it is saveing the address(?) of the correct values?

Here is my piece of code:

```
FILE* ifp;
ifp = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
int n = 10;

int* readbuf;
readbuf = (int *) malloc (n * sizeof(int));

for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
  int j = 0;
  fscanf (ifp, "%d", &j);
  j = readbuf[i];
  printf ("\n j = %d and readbuf = %d", j, readbuf[i]);
}
fclose(ifp);
```

Would the code be different if the input file contains following sequence:

```
0
1
2
3
...
```

Comment: To read a line you could use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). There is a example too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix it :

```
readbuf[i] = j;
```

instead of

```
j = readbuf[i];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now I look at it and all I can think is /facepalm

Comment: Don't let that bring you down. It happens even to the best programmers sometimes.